# Deploying Rails App with webpack to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I created my rails with [this template](http://github.com/lewagon/rails-templates) that included webpack. But i still wrote my javascript code in app/assets/javascript. Now I am trying to deploy my app to heroku and it keeps failing. I get this error

> remote:        /tmp/build_6f0656280cbbda40c5832ccb79fc1783/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:432:in `block in replace_bin_path': can't find executable webpack for gem webpacker (Gem::Exception)

The main error seems to be "cant find executable webpack for gem webpacker". I have no idea how to solve it. This is my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.3.5'

gem 'figaro'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'puma'
gem 'rails', '5.1.4'
gem 'redis'
gem 'cloudinary'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.2'
gem 'rails_admin', '~> 1.2'
group :production do
 gem 'pg', '~> 0.20'
end



gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails'

gem 'uglifier'
gem 'webpacker'
gem 'devise'
gem 'ransack'
gem 'trix'


gem "letter_opener", group: :development


group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :development, :test do
  # gem 'binding_of_caller'
  # gem 'better_errors'

  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
```

Comment: Try following the guide [here](https://crypt.codemancers.com/posts/2016-03-18-rails-webpack-heroku/) or using [this buildpack](https://github.com/febeling/webpack-rails-buildpack)

Comment: They both did not work unfortunately. Do you know how i can completely delete webpack and all it dependencies from the app?

Answer (score 2):

Breaking changes in 3.3.0

https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#330---2018-03-03

`bundle exec rails webpacker:binstubs`